# Why does this WebRequest to sony.com throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

My goal is to write a C# method that validates if a url points to a valid online resource. It currently looks something like this:

```
string url = "http://www.sony.com/";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   var msg = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? "OK" : "Dead Link";
   Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

This code throws an exception, even though I can browse to the sony url in a web browser. At first I thought their web server didn't support HEAD. Not sure if some don't? But it still throws an exception with GET. Any suggestions how to better write this code to handle cases such as this?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out. Sorry I should have posted that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site requires `User-Agent` header. Add this line:

```
request.UserAgent = "SO/1.0";
```

Comment: Yeah, just had to wait 5 minutes before it will let me.

Comment: May I know what user-agent it is? Thanks

Comment: @Alex SO (Stackoverflow) :) Shorter than: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)`