# Check URL is working or not using c#.net

Tags: c#

while i am check URL using Web request and web Response method.

```
bool result = false;
        try
        {
            if (!url.Contains("http://")) url = "http://" + url;
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            { if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) result = true; }
        }
        catch
        {
            return result;
        }
        return result;
```

But while i am check into this URL "http://payments.rctrustee.org/" am getting error. so i get the result is false. But i check into browser this URL is working.

i need this result true; how can i change my code.

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: seems there have similar question before... [Why does this WebRequest to sony.com throw an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542591/why-does-this-webrequest-to-sony-com-throw-an-exception/24542619?noredirect=1#comment38009389_24542619)

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following code:

```
try
            {
               if (!url.Contains("http://")) url = "http://" + url;
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);

                WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Url Exists");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (ex.Message.Contains("remote name could not be resolved"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Url is Invalid");
                }
            }
```